# Powershell: Convert get-adpermission object to get-aduser object

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to run a report of users with Send-As rights to mailboxes. I'm using the following code which is working fine:

```
$sa_user = Get-Mailbox -id <mailbox> | Get-ADPermission | where { ($_.ExtendedRights -like "*Send-As*") -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) }
```

But the ${sa_user.User} data can be rather "unhelpful" and I've been asked to provide more useful data (namingly: Department, CanonicalName, and DisplayName).

I'd like to tie the $sa_user adpermission object to an aduser object, as it has all those properties I need for the report. I've tried:

```
$ad_user = Get-ADUser -id $sa_user.identity
```

But $sa_user.identity is for the mailbox, not the user. So I tried:

```
$ad_user = Get-ADUser -id $sa_user.User
```

But I get only errors that Get-ADUser cmdlet Identify can't find the value given by $sa_user.User.

So my question is; How do I get the aduser object based off available properties from the adpermission object?...Or any other way or shortcut or intermediary to get there?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ad_user = Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties * | where-object {$_.CanonicalName -eq $sa_user.Identity}
```

Comment: As mentioned, $sa_user.identity is populated with the mailbox value and not with each of the users that have access to it. Running that command returns the aduser mailbox object, not the users.

Comment: The AD attribute "CanonicalName" is the same as the "Identity" attribute for Get-Mailbox | Get-ADPermission

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ad_user = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties msDS-PrincipalName | where-object {$_.'msDS-PrincipalName' -eq $sa_user.User}
```

OR

```
$ad_user = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties sAMAccountName | where-object {$_.sAMAccountName -eq ($sa_user.User -replace ".+\\")}
```

.

**Edit 01.12.2022**

After I noticed that filtering that way could be possible very slow I tried something different. Here is the whole code to loop trought send-as authorized users/objects. You only have to define a searchbase:

```
function Convert-CN2DN([string]$cn) {
    $obj = $cn.Split('/')
    if(-not $obj[0].Contains('.')) {
        $cn
    } else {
        [string]$DN = 'CN=' + $obj[$obj.count - 1]
        for ($i = $obj.count - 2; $i -ge 1; $i--) { $DN += ',OU=' + $obj[$i] }
        $obj[0].split('.') | ForEach-Object { $DN += ',DC=' + $_ }
        $DN
    }
}

$user_NTAUTHORITY = "NT AUTHORITY" # This is language specific. For example in german: "NT-AUTORITÄT"
$Searchbase = "" # <--- define a searchbase

$MailBoxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $Searchbase
foreach($Mailbox in $MailBoxes) { 
    $RecipientPermissions = $Mailbox | Get-RecipientPermission | ? { -not ($_.Trustee -match $user_NTAUTHORITY) -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false)} 
    foreach($RecipientPermission in $RecipientPermissions) { 
        if($RecipientPermission.Trustee) {
        
            $MailboxUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $Mailbox.DistinguishedName -Properties description,msExchResourceDisplay | Select ObjectClass,msExchResourceDisplay,description,Name
                            
            $SendAsObject_DN = Convert-CN2DN $RecipientPermission.Trustee
            if($SendAsObject_DN -ne $RecipientPermission.Trustee) { # When converting was successful. (Just in case of deleted users.)
                $SendAsObject = Get-ADObject -Identity $SendAsObject_DN -properties mail | Select Name,ObjectClass,distinguishedName,mail
            } else { 
                $SendAsObject = ""
            }
            
            # Now you could work with
            # $MailboxUser
            # $SendAsObject    
        } 
    }
}
```